# coreNLP in R: Ledu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotation; not found

Tags: r, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have been given a code in R to extract the sentiment of a list of texts and save it on a data frame, it is for a Sentiment Analysis project. I am new to r and coreNLP so I have been solving problems with memory and things like that, but I am still not sure how to solve everything. The tripadvisor data frame in the code contains reviews from the TripAdvisor webpage, I want to extract sentiments from them. TripAdvisor$titleopinion is the column with this data.

The error that I get is: Error in rJava::.jcall(volatiles$cNLP, "Ledu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotation;",  : 
  method process with signature (I)Ledu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotation; not found

The commands I run in every R session are:

1. Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121')
2. options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")

My pc has 8G of RAM and I sometimes get out of memory problems. The dali1.csv that I am loading contains about 450 instances of text that I want to extract the sentiment from.

The code is the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("statsmaths/coreNLP")
#coreNLP::downloadCoreNLP()
library(coreNLP)

initCoreNLP("C:/TFG/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31")

# Read the data
TripAdvisor <- read.csv("C:/TFG/Data/dali/dali1ENG.csv")

# Creating sentiment label
TripAdvisor$SentimentValue <- NA
TripAdvisor$SentimentValue <- ifelse(TripAdvisor$rating <= 2, "negative", 
                                     ifelse(TripAdvisor$rating == 3, "neutral",
                                            ifelse(TripAdvisor$rating >= 4, "positive", TripAdvisor$SentimentValue)))

# Predict sentiment with coreNLP
TripAdvisor$SentimentCoreNLP <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(TripAdvisor)){
  print(i)
  pos <- 0
  neg <- 0

  opinion <- TripAdvisor$titleopinion[i]
  opinion.df <- getSentiment(annotateString(opinion))

  for(j in 1:nrow(opinion.df)){
    if(opinion.df$sentiment[j]=="Verypositive"){
      pos = pos + 2
    } else if(opinion.df$sentiment[j]=="Positive"){
      pos = pos + 1
    } else if(opinion.df$sentiment[j]=="Negative"){
      neg = neg + 1
    } else if(opinion.df$sentiment[j]=="Verynegative"){
      neg = neg + 2
    }
  }

  TripAdvisor$pos[i] <- pos
  TripAdvisor$neg[i] <- neg

}

TripAdvisor$SentimentCoreNLP <- ifelse(TripAdvisor$pos > TripAdvisor$neg, "positive", 
                                       ifelse(TripAdvisor$pos < TripAdvisor$neg, "negative", "neutral"))

write.csv(TripAdvisor, file="C:/TFG/Data/dali/daliXENG.csv")

# Analysing SentimentValue vs. SentimentCoreNLP

# Table
table(TripAdvisor$SentimentCoreNLP, TripAdvisor$SentimentValue)
#100*(table(TripAdvisor$SentimentCoreNLP, TripAdvisor$SentimentValue)/(nrow(TripAdvisor)))
```

This code is supposed to work, the person who gave it to me used it without problems in a machine with a i3 and 8G RAM. Any insight about the problems of memory and this annotator missing are welcome and appreciated. Sorry for my bad english, I am still learning :)

If I am missing some required information please tell me so I can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I just got the answer, I think the problem might be that the titleopinion column's type was factor instead of character. I fixed this doing 
TripAdvisor$titleopinion <- as.character(TripAdvisor$titleopinion).

If someone reads this, I am new and I dont know what I am supposed to do, should I delete the question?